# Sum of next n rows in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which is grouped at product store day_id level Say it looks like the below and I need to create a column with rolling sum

```
prod store day_id visits 
111  123   1          2 
111  123   2          3
111  123   3          1
111  123   4          0
111  123   5          1
111  123   6          0
111  123   7          1
111  123   8          1
111  123   9          2
```

need to create a dataframe as below

```
prod store day_id visits rolling_4_sum  cond
111  123   1          2  6              1
111  123   2          3  5              1
111  123   3          1  2              1
111  123   4          0  2              1
111  123   5          1  4              0
111  123   6          0  4              0
111  123   7          1  NA             0
111  123   8          1  NA             0
111  123   9          2  NA             0
```

i am looking for create a
 **cond column**: that recursively checks a condition , say if rolling_4_sum     is greater than 5 then make the next 4 rows as 1 else do nothing ,i.e. even if the condition is not met retain what was already filled before , do this check for each row until 7 th row.

How can i achieve this using python ? i am trying

```
d1['rolling_4_sum'] = d1.groupby(['prod', 'store']).visits.rolling(4).sum()
```

but getting an error.

Comment: If you want a rolling sum you should use the `sum` method rather than the `mean` method.

Comment: yeah, corrected , but still getting the following TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

Comment: Your error is because of groupby.  It doesn't make sense to group the data by some columns and then put it back in the same dataframe. If it's grouped, that's a new dataframe with its own index, so work with that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formation of rolling sums can be done with [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html#pandas.Series.rolling) method, using boxcar window:

```
df['rolling_4_sum'] = df.visits.rolling(4, win_type='boxcar', center=True).sum().shift(-2)
```

The shift by -2 is because you apparently want the sums to be placed at the left edge of the window.

Next, the condition about rolling sums being less than 4:

```
df['cond'] = 0
for k in range(1, 4):
    df.loc[df.rolling_4_sum.shift(k) < 7, 'cond'] = 1
```

A new column is inserted and filled with 0; then for each k=1,2,3,4, look k steps back; if the sum then less than 7, then set the condition to 1.

Comment: thanks zaq, rolling part is working very well , however there was a mistake in my question , the condition was df.loc[df.rolling_4_sum > 5] and not 4 , i wanted the next 4 rows as 1 , and not the previous 4, Also i noticed , your 2nd query is shifting the whole data , 4 rows back. it should not change the shift the whole data back.

Comment: Okay so I replaced 4 by 7. `df.shift` does not modify df, it returns a copy with the rows shifted. I did have a sign error in this one: it should be `shift(k)`. The meaning is that after shift(k) we are looking at the data k steps back, and using that to decide whether cond should be changed. So the effect is that if something is <7, the next 4 rows are changed.